# (Primer C++ Sales_item.h) Can't seem to complie the example class

Tags: c++

I am using the ebook Primer c++ and I have reached the chapter in which I am supposed create a program that gets input of names of 2 books, price and number sold, and outputs the sum of earnings/average sale price.
I am tasked with pasting the code they have given me in a new class inside the project and than use it with my main class, I couldn't compile the code the compiler (both codeblocks and VS express) are showing an error when I do.

(Note that this is before I started writing any code of my own so it is probably a problem in the way I have created the class, or the compiler)
(To create a class I clicked on File>New class - named it Sales_item and finished, than it asked me if I wanna associate it with the project I'm working on {empty project with only empty main method} I clicked yes and pasted the code)

```
/*
 * This file contains code from "C++ Primer, Fifth Edition", by Stanley B.
 * Lippman, Josee Lajoie, and Barbara E. Moo, and is covered under the
 * copyright and warranty notices given in that book:
 * 
 * "Copyright (c) 2013 by Objectwrite, Inc., Josee Lajoie, and Barbara E. Moo."
 * 
 * 
 * "The authors and publisher have taken care in the preparation of this book,
 * but make no expressed or implied warranty of any kind and assume no
 * responsibility for errors or omissions. No liability is assumed for
 * incidental or consequential damages in connection with or arising out of the
 * use of the information or programs contained herein."
 * 
 * Permission is granted for this code to be used for educational purposes in
 * association with the book, given proper citation if and when posted or
 * reproduced.Any commercial use of this code requires the explicit written
 * permission of the publisher, Addison-Wesley Professional, a division of
 * Pearson Education, Inc. Send your request for permission, stating clearly
 * what code you would like to use, and in what specific way, to the following
 * address: 
 * 
 *     Pearson Education, Inc.
 *     Rights and Permissions Department
 *     One Lake Street
 *     Upper Saddle River, NJ  07458
 *     Fax: (201) 236-3290
*/ 

/* This file defines the Sales_item class used in chapter 1.
 * The code used in this file will be explained in
 * Chapter 7 (Classes) and Chapter 14 (Overloaded Operators)
 * Readers shouldn't try to understand the code in this file
 * until they have read those chapters.
*/

#ifndef SALESITEM_H
// we're here only if SALESITEM_H has not yet been defined 
#define SALESITEM_H

// Definition of Sales_item class and related functions goes here
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Sales_item {
// these declarations are explained section 7.2.1, p. 270 
// and in chapter 14, pages 557, 558, 561
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Sales_item&);
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Sales_item&);
friend bool operator<(const Sales_item&, const Sales_item&);
friend bool 
operator==(const Sales_item&, const Sales_item&);
public:
    // constructors are explained in section 7.1.4, pages 262 - 265
    // default constructor needed to initialize members of built-in type
    Sales_item() = default;
    Sales_item(const std::string &book): bookNo(book) { }
    Sales_item(std::istream &is) { is >> *this; }
public:
    // operations on Sales_item objects
    // member binary operator: left-hand operand bound to implicit this pointer
    Sales_item& operator+=(const Sales_item&);

    // operations on Sales_item objects
    std::string isbn() const { return bookNo; }
    double avg_price() const;
// private members as before
private:
    std::string bookNo;      // implicitly initialized to the empty string
    unsigned units_sold = 0; // explicitly initialized
    double revenue = 0.0;
};

// used in chapter 10
inline
bool compareIsbn(const Sales_item &lhs, const Sales_item &rhs) 
{ return lhs.isbn() == rhs.isbn(); }

// nonmember binary operator: must declare a parameter for each operand
Sales_item operator+(const Sales_item&, const Sales_item&);

inline bool 
operator==(const Sales_item &lhs, const Sales_item &rhs)
{
    // must be made a friend of Sales_item
    return lhs.units_sold == rhs.units_sold &&
           lhs.revenue == rhs.revenue &&
           lhs.isbn() == rhs.isbn();
}

inline bool 
operator!=(const Sales_item &lhs, const Sales_item &rhs)
{
    return !(lhs == rhs); // != defined in terms of operator==
}

// assumes that both objects refer to the same ISBN
Sales_item& Sales_item::operator+=(const Sales_item& rhs) 
{
    units_sold += rhs.units_sold; 
    revenue += rhs.revenue; 
    return *this;
}

// assumes that both objects refer to the same ISBN
Sales_item 
operator+(const Sales_item& lhs, const Sales_item& rhs) 
{
    Sales_item ret(lhs);  // copy (|lhs|) into a local object that we'll return
    ret += rhs;           // add in the contents of (|rhs|) 
    return ret;           // return (|ret|) by value
}

std::istream& 
operator>>(std::istream& in, Sales_item& s)
{
    double price;
    in >> s.bookNo >> s.units_sold >> price;
    // check that the inputs succeeded
    if (in)
        s.revenue = s.units_sold * price;
    else 
        s = Sales_item();  // input failed: reset object to default state
    return in;
}

std::ostream& 
operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Sales_item& s)
{
    out << s.isbn() << " " << s.units_sold << " "
        << s.revenue << " " << s.avg_price();
    return out;
}

double Sales_item::avg_price() const
{
    if (units_sold) 
        return revenue/units_sold; 
    else 
        return 0;
}
#endif
```

And this is the error -

```
||=== Build: Debug in Sales_item (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
include\Sales_item.h|56|warning: defaulted and deleted functions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11|
include\Sales_item.h|70|warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11|
include\Sales_item.h|71|warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11|
include\Sales_item.h|45|error: constructor required before non-static data member for 'Sales_item::units_sold' has been parsed|
include\Sales_item.h|45|error: constructor required before non-static data member for 'Sales_item::revenue' has been parsed|
C:\Users\Tomer\Desktop\C++\Code\Sales_item\src\Sales_item.cpp|3|error: definition of explicitly-defaulted 'Sales_item::Sales_item()'|
include\Sales_item.h|56|error: 'Sales_item::Sales_item()' explicitly defaulted here|
C:\Users\Tomer\Desktop\C++\Code\Sales_item\src\Sales_item.cpp|8|error: definition of implicitly-declared 'Sales_item::~Sales_item()'|
||=== Build failed: 5 error(s), 3 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Sorry for the bad English.

Comment: Pro-tip: Do not buy the ebook of C++ primer. Get the book.

Comment: Why is that? what is wrong with the ebook?

Comment: Well firstly, is has formatting errors, with the code, and the actual text. secondly, some of the code examples are abruptly ended, and cut of. And thirdly, don't just take my word for it, [read about some ebook review for your self](https://www.amazon.com/Primer-5th-Stanley-B-Lippman/product-reviews/0321714113/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_hist_1?ie=UTF8&filterByStar=one_star&reviewerType=avp_only_reviews&showViewpoints=0&pageNumber=1).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should make your compiler or IDE to support the c++11 because the code used some new keywords. I test it and it works well with c++11.

Comment: As the compiler warned: "warning: defaulted and deleted functions only available with -std=c++11".
In general, always pay attention to compiler warnings.

Comment: Oh ok, that seems right, I read the first two lines at first and realized I have no clue what they mean and stopped, sorry

Comment: Where can I update my compiler? It is a new compiler I just downloaded (and believed to be the most recent one) where can I find a newer version?

Comment: use `g++ filename.cpp -std=c++11 -o outputname`, I ran the code successfully in cmd. For VS2015 I used, the code  is compiled successfully as well. If use code::block, you have to set it to support c++11.I do believe there is much information about how to set it to support c++11.Hope the [website](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html) is helpful for you.